# How to Prove a 3 dimensional curve isn't contained in a Quadratic Surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

So I'm given a curve parametrically as

$$ C = \begin{pmatrix} x = t \\ y  = t^2 \\ z = t^3 \end{pmatrix} $$

And  I wish to show that there doesn't exist a surface $S$ of the form

$$ A + Bx + Cy + Dz + Exy + Fxz + Gyz + Hx^2 + Iy^2 + Kz^2 = 0 $$

That contains said curve. But I'm not really sure how to do this?

### One Idea:

So in a simpler case of just showing that no surface $S$ of the form $A + Bx + Cy + Dz = 0$ contains the curve $C$, one can observe that $C$ has non-zero torsion, whereas every curve bounded in a plane $S$ will have to have $0$ torsion, so clearly $C$ is not contained in $S$.

This motivates me to then ask: how do I generalize "Torsion" to a more general measure that is bounded for all quadratic surfaces?

Comment: Umm... $C$ is contained in $xz - y^2 = 0$.

Comment: This is correct. Silly me

Comment: @DanielSchepler I should've just considered the more general case of an arbitrary polynomial in x,y,z let me edit this. The content of the question is then still valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a surface of that form containing $C$, namely that with equation $y^2-xz$.